# "Non-wiki" appears twice on user's page tooltip

Tags: support, profile-page, tooltips

In the user's page, when I put my mouse near the numbers next to the tags, I get this tooltip text:

> Asked 1 non-wiki questions with a total score of 2. Answered 10 non-wiki questions with a total score of 19.

"non-wiki" appears twice in the sentence! 
Should the first "non-wiki" be changed to "wiki"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you re-read carefully, you'll see that the first number is for *questions*, while the second is for *answers*. This is correct.